# Unable to assign Thread Priorities

Tags: java, multithreading

Actually I am new in java threads field. I want to implement Earliest Deadline First Scheduling Algorithm of Real Time systems. I have generated the code for following tasks:
1. Tasks are generate after every 1 second.
// Main.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main 
{
     public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
     {    
          Node node;
          Random rand = new Random();
          int Threshold = 10;
          long Period,Deadline,Duration;

          System.out.println("Task Generation Starts....\n");
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "  START\n");
          for(int i =1;i<=Threshold;i++)
          {  
              Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
              long m = c.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
              Duration = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
              Period =   rand.nextInt(10)+1;
              Deadline = Period + m;
              node = new Node("Task"+i, m, Duration, Period, Deadline);
              new Tasks("Task"+i,node);
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          } 
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "  STOP\n");
    }
}
```

1. This tasks passes to one tasks class that implents Runnable.

// Tasks.java

```
    import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.lang.Thread;

    class Tasks implements Runnable
    { 
      Thread T;
      String taskname;

      Node task;
      TaskPriority taskpriority = new TaskPriority();


      public Tasks(String S,Node newtask)
       {
          this.taskname=S;
          this.task = newtask;
          T = Thread.currentThread();
          T.setName(taskname);
          T = new Thread(this, T.getName());
          System.out.println(T.getName()+ "Starts Running");
          T.start();
       }

      public void run()
      { 
        try
        {
           taskpriority.insert(task);
           taskpriority.pop();

        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Tasks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,"error is"+ie.getMessage(),ie);
        }
    } 
}
```

1. From Tasks.java insert function of taskpriority.java has been called and immediatly after that pop() function that calls the Earliest Deadline Function Class.
2. What I want is

1st Thread of Maximum Priority arrives for execution. Given Thread has following details:
Task   ArrivalTime   WCET   Period(Cycle)    Deadline
Task1   38          4Sec.     6               44 Sec.

Tasks execution starts at 38 sec. Worst Case Execution Time (WCET) is of 4 sec. Task1 starts at 38 sec, run for 1 sec and calculates its remaining (4-1=3sec.) After this 1 sec run scheduler check whether some other task arrive or not. If Second task arrives at 39sec. 
Task    ArrivalTime  WCET  Period(Cycle)  Deadline
Task2    39          4Sec.    5            44 Sec.

Now EDF will check the time left to achieve the deadline of both tasks: Task1 (In Task1 actual arrival time is 38 but after 1 sec of execution it becomes 39) (44-39 =5 sec) and Task2 (44-39=5sec.) old task will continue and again after another second i.e. at 40 sec. EDF scheduler will check again after 1 sec. and Task3 has arrived. 
   Task   ArrivalTime   WCET   Period(Cycle)   Deadline 
   Task3    40         2Sec.      5             45 Sec.

Now again check the time left to achieve the deadline of all tasks Task1 is running and complete its 2 unit of time from 4 hence Task1(44-40 = 2Sec.), Task2(44-39=5sec) and Task3 (45-40=5 sec.). Based on these left time of all three tasks, Scheduler assign Maximum Priority to Task1 and it preempts the Task4 as well as Task2. In this way this given algorithm will work for upcoming tasks (Here Threshold is 10).

Here I am unable to change/assign the priorities to the threads after every 1 second. And how can i come to know that which thread is about to come.

//EDF Code

```
    public void EarliestDF() throws InterruptedException, SecurityException
    {        
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
         long a = calendar.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
         System.out.println("Task\t\tArrivalTime\tWCET\t\tPeriod(Cycle)\t  Deadline");
         System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName()+"\t\t"+a+"\t\t"+task.duration+"Sec.\t\t"+task.period +"\t\t"+task.deadline+" Sec.");
         System.out.println("\n");

         Execution(task);


         Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
         long start = calendar2.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);

         long newP = task.period-task.duration;

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" is waiting for next phase from :\t"+start + " Sec.");

         Thread.sleep(newP * 1000);

         Calendar calendar3 = new GregorianCalendar();
         long stop = calendar3.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
         System.out.println(task.taskname +" execution arrive again at:\t"+stop + "Sec.");
         System.out.println("\n");

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"is in Process again\t");
         newQ();
        }

   public void Execution(Node task) throws InterruptedException
   {

       if(task.Arrival+task.duration<=task.deadline)
     {
         System.out.print("Execution of"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"has started at ");
         Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
         long start = calendar2.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
         System.out.print(start+" Sec.\n");  

         while (time<=task.duration)
         {      
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(time+" Sec...");
                task.duration=task.duration-time;
                System.out.println("Time Left"+ task.duration);
                task.Arrival = start + time;
                System.out.println("Task   "  + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println("\n");
                time++;
         }

                Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
                long stop = calendar1.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
                System.out.println("Total Completion Time of"+Thread.currentThread().getName() + "is:\t"+stop+" Sec.");
         }
   }
```

From this code i am not getting the results one by one....If any thread has maximum priority it should preempt the Minimum priority Thread. I am unable to assign the priorities to threads. This is my main problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If your problem is too long it can mean a) people won't read it. b) the problem needs more investigation to work out exactly what the problem is.  Can you write a short paragraph with a question at the start which describe all you need to know about your problem?

Comment: As far as I know, the thread priorities are like an advice to the JVM, you have no guarantee that "high priority" threads are going to be executed first that "low priority" ones.